# How to determine which grid does a coordinate lie in, in list of multiple polygons(grids)

Tags: python, json, location

I'm trying to calculate the count and the most used hashtag texts of tweets made from each grid cell. The grid file and the tweet file are in json format.The grid file consist of 16 grid cells which have a separate id for themselves, and I need to find out how many tweets were made from each grid.

The grid file consist of grid id, the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax and 5 polygon coordinates given the first and last coordinates are same of the polygon.
I tried to compare each and every tweet location-"after extracting them from the json file and stored them into a dictionary",with the xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax.However I wasn't getting a proper output, the output which I was getting was displaying that the tweets were located only in three grids i.e C2,C3 and D3 grid cells, which isn't correct.
In the code below, lst contains all the properties of grid with their id,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax and polygon coordinates and dic contains all the values of location and text that I have extracted from the json file

```
lt =[]
def match_tweets():

    for d in dic.values():
        for x in lst:

            if ((x['xmin'][0]<= tweet_long[1][0][0] and tweet_long[1][0][0]<=x['xmax'][0]) and (x['ymin'][0]<=tweet_lat[0][0][0] and tweet_lat[0][0][0]<x['ymax'][0])):
                x['count']+=1
                return lst.append(x['grid_id'])
```

This was the function which I used to compare the values, the tweet latitudes and longitudes were stored in a list which has dictionary so there are many indexes to access the values of it.
The output which i was getting was
Counter({C2:210,D3:57,C2:47})
I used counter to calculate the number of id of similar value.

The expected value must display all the grid id with the number of tweets made like
(C2: number of tweets)
(A2: number of tweets)
so on till the last grid cells

Grid file format

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4283" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "A1", "xmin": 144.700000, "xmax": 144.850000, "ymin": -37.650000, "ymax": -37.500000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 144.7, -37.5 ], [ 144.85, -37.5 ], [ 144.85, -37.65 ], [ 144.7, -37.65 ], [ 144.7, -37.5 ] ] ] } },  
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "A2", "xmin": 144.850000, "xmax": 145.000000, "ymin": -37.650000, "ymax": -37.500000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 144.85, -37.5 ], [ 145.0, -37.5 ], [ 145.0, -37.65 ], [ 144.85, -37.65 ], [ 144.85, -37.5 ] ] ] } },  

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "A3", "xmin": 145.000000, "xmax": 145.150000, "ymin": -37.650000, "ymax": -37.500000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 145.0, -37.5 ], [ 145.15, -37.5 ], [ 145.15, -37.65 ], [ 145.0, -37.65 ], [ 145.0, -37.5 ] ] ] } },
```

dictionary for tweets is given as:

`{0:[[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
1: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
2: [[[-37.94917514]], [[144.92501796]], [['tb', 'tasmania']]],`

where the keys of dic are just a number assigned, the first value is the latitude, second value is the longitude and the last one consist of all the hashtags

lst is a list of all the properties of the grid file which stores the data as

```
[{'id': 'A1',
'xmin': [144.7],
'xmax': [144.85],
'ymin': [-37.65],
'ymax': [-37.5],
'coordinates': [[[144.7, -37.5],
[144.85, -37.5],
[144.85, -37.65],
[144.7, -37.65],
[144.7, -37.5]]],
'count': 0},
```

Here the count values which I have added as an extra is to increase it if there is a tweet that occurs in the respective grid

Comment: Example of the data showing the layout of the JSON in the grid tweet files are required to answer your question. Please [edit] your question and add this.

Comment: @martineau the grid file has been added and displayed in proper format by chitown

Comment: That helps, but the tweets location dictionary you created "after extracting them from the json file and stored them into a dictionary" is also needed. What's required is a definition of _all_ the input data.

Comment: @martineau added the dictionary data for the first 3 keys